# oracle number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

Tags: sql

I keep getting an error saying The number of columns in the foreign-key referenced list is not equal to the number of columns in the referenced list.

This is the line I am getting the error on.

```
      foreign key(EID, Lastname, Firstname, Midinitial) references employee,
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

```
create table employee(
  EID varchar(20) primary key,
  Lastname varchar(20),
  Firstname varchar(20),
  Midinitial char(1),
  gender char(1),
  street varchar(20),
  city varchar(20)
);

create table works(
  EID varchar(20) primary key,
  Lastname varchar(20),
  Firstname varchar(20),
  Midinitial char(1),
  company_name varchar(20),
  salary numeric(5,0),
  foreign key(EID, Lastname, Firstname, Midinitial) references employee,
  foreign key(company_name) references company
);

create table company(
  company_name varchar(20) primary key,
  city varchar(20),
  foreign key(city)references employee
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Primary Key from Employees only:

```
foreign key(EID) references employee
```